# How to pass spiltted string value to text box dynamically in jsp

Tags: java, jsp

I am getting the value from one page to another page by using query string here i am getting `id=10` then so i spitted this value I need to pass `10` only to text box how can i pass this value.

When I take like this

```
value="<%=request.getQueryString()%>"
```

My text box value it shows `id=10` but i need value only `10`
    how can i pass this value to my text box

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
value=<%=request.getQueryString().replace("id=", "")%>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the value using get parameter

```
value=<%=request.getParameter("id")%>
```

But please get the value in variable.

```
<% String idValue=""+request.getParameter("id")%>
```

Assign the value to your text box

```
value=<%=request.getParameter("id")%>
```

Comment: HI,@muthu vignesh i am taking `String Batch=request.getQueryString();
        
        String[] BatchId1=Batch.split("=");` i  need to pass `BatchId1[1]` to my text box value